# Leaflet Map not going over the edge of the map

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

Im using a leaftlet map to display a map from a game. And its working find but i just want it to not go out of bounds of the map and let the user just drag into emptiness.

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
});
var bounds = [
  [0, 0],
  [937, 937]
];
var image = L.imageOverlay('Images/map.png', bounds).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

```css
.map {
  background-color: #08001A;
}

#map {
  height: 98vh;
  width: 90vh;
  background-color: #020208;
}

.map-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-block: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-container">
  <div id="map">
  </div>
</div>
```